# How to run cypress test using tags from saucectl

Tags: cypress, saucelabs

I am able to run cypress test on saucelab using saucectl. Now the ask is to run tests with required tags like smoke or regression. Is there any configuration that I can do in confg.yml file or pass value from CLI to run tag specific test.

Answer (score 0):

saucectl leaves much of the test organisation up to your test runners which is unfortunate, because Cypress itself doesn't have in-built support for running tests via tag.

There's a partial workaround that might suit, based on file location.  In your `config.yml`, you can specify individual `suites` ([see here](https://docs.saucelabs.com/web-apps/automated-testing/cypress/yaml/#suites)) which let you provide individual `config` options to Cypress. You're still limited to running individual files (by passing them to the `testFiles` option; [see the docs](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/references/configuration#Folders-Files)).

This isn't a problem if you only want to run entire files; Just include the file in each Suite you want it to be part of.

## Glob-based "tag" Selection

By making clever use of globbing in the `testFiles` option, you can avoid having to update your saucectl config file every time you add a new test file.

This removes the risk of forgetting to add files to their respective groups, and also helps keep information about each spec file (eg, what kind of spec it is) closer to the file itself.

### Example

#### Suite Files

Say your tests look like this.  Each file contains tests that should only run on a specific browser (or combination of browsers).

```
specs/
  ui/
    login_chromeOnly_spec.js
    login_firefoxOnly_spec.js
  accounting/
    jsMathBugFix_ieOnly_spec.js
    chromiumCantCount_edgeOnly_chromeOnly_spec.js
```

#### config.yml

Here's the suites component of config.yml.  Each suite has a unique glob for `testFiles` which finds all tests in your specs folder which ends in the respective `_browserOnly_spec.js` value.

```
  suites:
    - name: "Where There's Smoke There's"
      browser: "firefox"
      platformName: "Windows 10"
      config:
        testFiles: ["specs/**/*firefoxOnly*_spec.js"]

    - name: "Cream on"
      browser: "chrome"
      platformName: "Windows 10"
      config:
        testFiles: ["specs/**/*chromeOnly*_spec.js"]

    - name: "Livin' on the"
      browser: "edge"
      platformName: "Windows 10"
      config:
        testFiles: ["specs/**/*edgeOnly*_spec.js", "specs/**/*ieOnly*_spec.js"]
```

#### How it works

The first glob, `["specs/**/*firefoxOnly*_spec.js"]`, will match
`specs/ui/login_firefoxOnly_spec.js`.

The second glob, `["specs/**/*chromeOnly*_spec.js"]`, matches `specs/ui/login_chromeOnly_spec.js` AND `specs/accounting/chromiumCantCount_edgeOnly_chromeOnly_spec.js`

The third suite has two entries in the glob array, `["specs/**/*edgeOnly*_spec.js", "specs/**/*ieOnly*_spec.js"]`.  It will include all files which match *any* of those globs; In this case it matches any file tagged with *either* `edgeOnly` or `ieOnly`, which is `specs/accounting/jsMathBugFix_ieOnly_spec.js` and `chromiumCantCount_edgeOnly_chromeOnly_spec.js`.

## Individual spec alternatives

If you want to have individual specs within a file tagged... You're out of luck at the moment.  I can think of a couple of ways of doing this:

1. Use a plugin to add tags to Cypress, then pass the tag selection option via `config.yml`
2. Send a PR to Cypress to add tags natively
3. Write a transpiler plugin to allow you to add tags to your tests, then have them transpiled into individual files (then use the glob approach)